# Swift 4 json array - how to get value

Tags: arrays, json, swift, alamofire

I have this code in Swift 4 and Alamofire:

```
Alamofire.request("http://xxxx.pl/id=1", method: .get, parameters: nil)
            .responseJSON { response in
let jsonResponse = JSON(response.result.value!)

let resData = jsonResponse["ranking"].array
print("XXXX: \(jsonResponse)")
}
            .responseString { response in
                if let error = response.result.error {
                    print(error)
                }
                if let value = response.result.value {
                    print(value)
                }
}
```

After running this code, I get a json with the following parameters:

```
XXXX: {
  "ranking" : {
    "dataWidoczneOd" : {
      "second" : 0,
      "year" : 2018,
      "month" : 2,
      "hourOfDay" : 0,
      "dayOfMonth" : 1,
      "minute" : 0
    }
    "opis" : "cx",
    "id" : 50971,
    "dataWidoczneDo" : {
      "second" : 0,
      "year" : 2018,
      "month" : 2,
      "hourOfDay" : 0,
      "dayOfMonth" : 31,
      "minute" : 0
    },
    "grupy" : [
      {
        "nazwa" : "yyy",
        "kod" : "yyy",
        "id" : 51032,
        "idkiPlikowGrafiki" : [
          "51034"
        ],
        "gracze" : [

          {
            "zakonczonaGra" : false,
            "imieINazwisko" : "zzzz yyyy",
            "email" : "tertretera@cccc.com",
            "liczbaZdobytychPunktow" : "0.0",
            "czasGry" : "0 min"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "nazwa" : "ttt",
        "kod" : "ttt",
        "id" : 50981,
        "idkiPlikowGrafiki" : [
          "50983",
          "50986"
        ],
        "gracze" : [

        ]
      }
    ],
    "nazwa" : "grupowy",
    "idkiPlikowGrafiki" : [
      "50976"
    ],
    "typ" : "GRUPA",
    "dataOd" : {
      "second" : 0,
      "year" : 2018,
      "month" : 2,
      "hourOfDay" : 0,
      "dayOfMonth" : 1,
      "minute" : 0
    }
  }
}
```

How can I get the values from this json array and save in variables:
- gracze (all values)
- idkiPlikowGrafiki (all values)
- typ (all values)
- kod (all values)
- dataWidoczneOd (all values)

?

Please help :)

Comment: are you using SwiftJSON

Comment: you can use SwiftyJSON to serialize the json. https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON

Comment: To both who recommend `SwiftyJSON`:  If you have no clue how to read and understand the structure of JSON the tool you're using is irrelevant. And in Swift 4 SwiftyJSON as a parsing tool is actually obsolete. The `Codable` protocol is more convenient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a model class for this response and parse it with, for example, Codable. [Here](https://klgraham.github.io/post/swift-codable-protocol/) is a good example.